# OS X Can't Access Netatalk Shares

Tags: macos, ubuntu, osx-snow-leopard, file-sharing, netatalk

In my home network, I have a server running Ubuntu 10.4, configured to share files to my MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard (10.6.8) with Netatalk and Avahi. It was working like a charm until one day it stopped working. I can see my server in Finder, I can enter a username and password, and it seems to accept it all, but Finder gets stuck "Connecting" until it times out.

I've checked the afpd.conf and AppleVolumes.default. They are all intact. My guess is that an update broke something, but I don't know how to troubleshoot it further. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not familiar using these tools, but Apple has been changing up their AFP/NFS/SMB protocols in Lion. Not sure if they changed stuff in 10.6 though, but just a heads up. If these tools use kerberos or something similar, each system clock will need to be within a few minutes of each other as well.

Comment: I know that they like tinkering with it a lot yea, that's why I'm guessing that's the culprit. Still, there's gotta be something that can be done..

Answer (score 1):

I checked out Netatalk's website, noticed several updates had been made since I installed it, so I updated my installation. I followed this guide: [Connect OS X Lion Time Machine to a Network Drive](http://beacon.wharton.upenn.edu/davekonopka/2011/07/connect-os-x-lion-time-machine-to-a-network-drive/) to manually compile it and install.

Still, even after update, the problem remained. I noticed that in the ./config summary, it said that the supported `cnid_schemes` for the AppleVolumes.default file were `dbd last tdb`. Mine was set to `cdb`.

Apparently among all the updates that Apple has done to AFP, they deprecated/deleted the `cnid_scheme: cdb`.

So I changed it and BAM! back to business.